# Reading data from Excel file prior to version 95

Tags: java, excel, parsing, excel-4.0

Apparently Excel 4.0 is still used and I have to read it in Java.

Neither [poi](http://poi.apache.org/) nor [jExcelAPI](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/), as great as they are, can parse them. I can't find anything on them, especially with Java. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at **[JODconverter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter)**, which uses OpenOffice, where the [list of support documents](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Framework/Article/Filter/FilterList_OOo_3_0) includes MS Excel 4.

If you can't use it directly, maybe you can convert to an intermediate format that works for you.

Comment: Man, I wish I'd known about this when I had to implement code that turned MS Office files into PDF and HTML; I wound up using the OpenOffice Java API directly, which isn't pleasant.  But it definitely gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, Excel 4 had good support for reading and writing via DDE. If you're going way back, you might as well go *waaaay* back. I haven't used any myself, but Google shows several listings for Java DDE support. If nothing better pops up, you might give it a try.